# php each letter to images

Tags: php, html

I have a problem to put text into a image.

I have all letters in images on my folder named `tekst`.

Lets say I use `$userinfo->name` to get the user name and in this case the user is named `zippo`

Then I want the users name to return following HTML output:

```
<img src="tekst/z.png"><img src="tekst/i.png"><img src="tekst/p.png"><img src="tekst/p.png"><img src="tekst/o.png">
```

How can I do it with PHP to change each letter in the name to `<img src="tekst/?.png>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
<?php
$name = "zippo";
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($name); $i++) {
    echo '<img src="tekst/' . $name[$i] . '.png">';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function on your string and loop over result array as follows:

```
$letters = str_split($string);
foreach ($letters as $letter) {
   echo '<img src="tekst/' . $letter .  '.png" />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
    $letters = str_split($string);
foreach ($letters as $letter) {
   echo '<img src=".../tekst/' . $letter .  '.png" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a php file to convert your text to image :

```
<?php
/* image.php */

// Receive data
$char = $_GET['char'];
if(!empty($char)){
  // This will get the first character from $char
  $char = $char;
  // Create a 100*30 image
  $im = imagecreate(100, 30);

  // White background and blue text
  $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
  $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

  // Write the string at the top left
  imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $char, $textcolor);

  // Output the image
  header('Content-type: image/png');

  imagepng($im);
  imagedestroy($im);
}
?>
```

**Image String** http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php

Then split its name into chars

```
<?php
$string = 'abcdefgh'; // For example
$chars = str_split($string);
foreach ($chars as $char) {
   echo '<img src="tekst/image.php?char='.$char.'"/>';
}
?>
```

**str_split** http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

GOOD LUCK